# React final form not working with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I want to create a [react final form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) in a react-typescript environment.
I get an error  that I am missing "**onSubmit**" property in type {...} required by "**FormProps**". I checked the interface but can't figure why I am getting this error because I have that property set in place and defined.

**myfile.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
    this.validateHandler= this.validateHandler.bind(this);
  }

   onSubmitHandler(): void {
   }

   validateHandler(): void {

   }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler} // OK
          validate={this.validateHandler}
          render={ ( {handleSubmit, pristine, invalid} ) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


                <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || invalid}>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
           )}
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.d.ts (react final form)** - FormProps => Config => ...onSubmit

```
export const Form: React.ComponentType<FormProps>;

export interface FormProps extends Config, RenderableProps<FormRenderProps>{
  subscription?: FormSubscription;
  decorators?: Decorator[];
  initialValuesEqual?: (a?: object, b?: object) => boolean;
}

export interface Config<FormData = object> {
  debug?: DebugFunction
  destroyOnUnregister?: boolean
  initialValues?: object
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize?: boolean
  mutators?: { [key: string]: Mutator }
  onSubmit: (
    values: FormData,
    form: FormApi,
    callback?: (errors?: object) => void
  ) => object | Promise<object | undefined> | undefined | void
  validate?: (values: object) => object | Promise<object>
  validateOnBlur?: boolean
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props should be provided inside the opening tag of an element.Change your `render` method to this.

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form 
        onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler} // OK
        validate={this.validateHandler}
        render={ ( {handleSubmit, pristine, invalid} ) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || invalid}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        )}>  
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Isnt that exactly the same as he did?

Comment: If you carefully look at `myfile.tsx` in the question, you will see that props has not been provided inside `<Form>` tag but immediately after.

Comment: ah sorry. missed that :)